# Cual es la alternativa a Xincgc en JDK17?

Tags: java, batch

Este "codigo" me funcionaba en JRE8
"-Xincgc" "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" "-XX:+UseParNewGC"
Pero en la version JDK17 estas flags estan eliminadas... Hay una equivalencia posible?
No tengo idea de Java, solo necesito que el .bat funcione :(

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Has intentado ejecutar ese .bat sin esas etiquetas?

Comment: @FernandoCarraro Si, pero el cliente tiene 2 plugins de graficos, los cuales al activarlos se desactivan al instante dando errores. Cosa que no pasa en la version de JRE8

Answer (score 0):

Los parámetros `"-Xincgc" "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" "-XX:+UseParNewGC"` fueron deprecados en `JDK 9` y eliminados en `JDK 10`, esto fue porque el recolector de basura G1 fue liberado de su fase de pruebas y es el algoritmo que remplazo lo que estas utilizando, como solución cambiar tus 3 parámetros a uno `-XX:+UseG1GC` que debería comportarse de manera similar o mejor, claro que para estar seguro es necesario analizar el comportamiento de tu sistema y la cantidad de memoria que necesita

Aunque me surge la duda que `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"` y `-XX:+UseParNewGC` son dos recolectores de basura diferentes por lo que la JVM solo debió de seleccionar 1 de los 2 algoritmos pero no se como realiza la selección si es el que sea primer parámetro o el ultimo.

Comment: Buenas @Roberto E Moran . Me sale el mismo error que cuando no uso ninguno de los 3 parametros (Vacio) https://imgur.com/a/K6ZXyWd

Comment: El error que tienes no esta relacionado con los parámetros que comentas, el error esta relacionado a runelite que no puede iniciar los gráficos según veo la versión máxima soportada es JDK 11, prueba desactivar la aceleración de grafico con este parámetro `--mode=OFF` o instalar una JDK menor a la 11.

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido, Runelite permite desde JRE8 hasta JDK17, el tema es que OpenOSRS no permite menos que JDK11 (en la cual, ya está eliminadas las flags). Sin el bat, ambos ejecutan sin problema, creo que traen integrado el java

Comment: Segun el blog la el ultimo JDK que se ha agregado es el 16 https://runelite.net/blog/show/2021-05-12-1.7.7-Release.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar con JDK16 con -XX:+UseG1GC y sigue igual :(

Comment: Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1